# Howto make SELECT queries with variable size for filtering parameters?

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, android-room

With RoomBD I could make in a DAO a query like this one:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM table "
     + "WHERE field1 LIKE :param1 "
     + "OR field1 LIKE :param2 "
     + "OR field1 LIKE :param3")
public LiveData<List<Table>> filterTableData(String param1, String param2, String param3);
```

...but the point is that i need to do this kind of SELECT statement with a variable amount of filtering parameters, so I don't have to redundantly create multiple `filterTableData` methods in the DAO that would do exactly the same thing but with a different amount of filtering parameters. Is there a way to do so?

```
// XXX What I'd like it to be (SQL is pseudocode here)
@Query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE field1 LIKE :any_of_the_parameters")
public LiveData<List<Table>> filterTableData(ArrayList<String> params);
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I don't know RoomDB myself, but checking around a bit, I saw that it uses `NULLIF` to check for nulls and replace them. You can list all parameters and then do `OR field1 like nullif(:param2, field1)`. This will make the parameter optional. This will essentially, in the case of a null, inner join the table with itself, meaning it'll get the same results as if the parameter wasn't even there. Alternatively, you can use `AND (field1 LIKE :param OR :param IS NULL)`.

Comment: @jarlh I beg your pardon: what's a dbms (maybe Database Management System?). I use Android Room, if that counts as a DBMS...

Comment: The software reading SQL and that manages the tables and the data. Perhaps SQLite?

Comment: @jarlh Well, Android Room relies on SQLite, so... yes, I guess

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this yet, but according to [this link](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/Query), this might do the job for `OR`-like filtering:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE field1 IN(:params)")
LiveData<List<Table>> filterTableData(List<String> params);
```

However, I don't have any idea for `AND`-like filtering (yet)...

Answer (score 0):

add this in your database  class

```
 public byte [] get(String query){
        try {

            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);

            if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
                return  cursor.getBlob(0);
            }
            return null;

        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

and use this for retrive image

```
db_class = new DatabaseClass(MainActivity.this);
            byte [] img = db_class.get("SELECT IMG FROM data WHERE id = 1");
            if (img != null){
                Bitmap bitmap = convertbytearyrtobitmap(img);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

Create the query programatically with the list of parameters.

Comment: In a PC app I would just have done that already: but RoomDb forces me to work with DBs through its framework. Would RoomDB just let me add non-hardcoded strings to the `@Query` annotation? I wonder...

Comment: Please notice that the method that implements the @Query is part of an `interface`, but not any interface: a `@Dao` interface. Athough recently I learned that I could implement Room's DAOs as abstract classes as well.

Comment: I would just love that I could concatenate the SQL statements like I normally did in PHP, for example. But I am afraid that working with `RoomDB` library is not that simple. As far as I know, `@Query` annotations for DAOs (inherently needed for RoomDb) just let me pass a hardcoded query with special placeholders like `:field1` for DAO's method parameters. Although, I might not know the full potential of `@Query` annotations.

Comment: This is the problem with frameworks! You are constrained that's why I don't use them.

Comment: And I admire your disregard about frameworks, and I mean it for real. However, this question is specific about RoomDB framework for Android development.

Comment: No prob - of course I know nothing of RoomDB so I should have kept quiet - sorry.